# Move artifacts instead of copy after Hudson build

Tags: hudson, build-automation

We are using Hudson v.2.2.1

I noticed that Hudson makes a copy of the generated artifacts instead of a move. Is there a way to run any type of script after build that could remove those artifacts?

I was thinking about creating a new task for each project, but this seems to be a little overkill to me.

Or is there a way to get information about the build that triggered the post-build?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix to my issue was to install "Workspace Cleanup Plugin"